# Android License Verification Library and multiple Google Accounts

Tags: android

Does the Android License Verification Library support a device logged in to multiple Google accounts?

Does it use the first Google account to determine who purchased an app?

Comment: The docs say it uses the primary account.  How do you determine the primary account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer in the License service troublshooting page.

How do I verify that my licensing implementation is correct?

Before uploading the application to Market

If no application with that package name and version code is on Market, sign into a phone with your publisher account as the primary account, set the test response, and verify that your application behaves appropriately for those responses.

After uploading the application to Market
If you’ve uploaded the application with license-checking to Market (regardless of the current publish state of the application), sign into a phone with your publisher account or a license test account as the primary account, set the test response, and verify that your application behaves appropriately for those responses.

Note that the ServerManagedPolicy caches test LICENSED responses for only one minute. Normal (non-test) LICENSED responses will be cached longer.